# upload database records in a host

Tags: sql-server, host

It's my first website, I used asp.net and used mssql as database.

I uploaded project via filezilla and uploaded my .sql file via server and everything works fine: I can add/delete/upload records without a problem but my datas from database seems like didn't come with the uploaded script and sadly I need them.
I got a feeling like it's an easy question but I really couldn't find a solution in web, people must have thought it's really easy but I really stuck in here.

I found something like taking backup of database and uploading it; I took backup and don't know what to do with that .bak file.

Comment: Can you clarify "my datas from database seems like didn't come with the uploaded script". Also, if you can add/delete/update records, then what is not working? And one more question, how are you uploading our database?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I have user and products table. I can add/remove/upload user without a problem but i didn't create a method for adding products.I mean products were stable in my database. I inserted them in my db with sql management studio before upload of the project. I uploaded my database with my hosting provider website's database management service. It wanted a .sql file and I generated my database's script and uploaded it

Comment: what about the connection string used in the website?

Comment: My hosting provider gave me a connection string and I wrote it in my project's web.config file. It created the connection